# Live demo шаблона

Tags: шаблоны, php, iframe, html, css

http://www.woothemes.com/ http://www.yootheme.com/ http://www.themezilla.com/ http://themeforest.net/ - У всех их есть живое демо шаблонов. Выглядит однотипным, все используют один и тот же GET запрос - следовательно это готовый вариант. Не подскажите, как сделать такое, демо, как у них. А точнее с помощью чего это сделано?

Вот ссылка на один из примеров: http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=artificer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через обычный iframe, откройте страницу и посмотрите ее исходный код.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это iframe. Даже больше скажу - вижу. Мне бы та полосочка с переключением...

Comment: Опять же, в исходнике... Вещаете на выпадающий список событие, берете выбранное название и при помощи того же js меняете ссылку в iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Просто скопируй через Opera нажми Ctrl+S и выбери Тип файла: HTML файл с изображениями и все. Потом у тебя сохранится папка с html файлом, вот тебе готовый шаблон теперь только остается посмотреть как все это устроенно, ну а в папке собственно и будут все js и css файлы.

Comment: Файлы я то умею доставать=) Я просто думал, что там PHP используется или еще что.. Спасибо за информацию. Буду пробовать

Comment: К сожалению серверный язык такой как PHP просто в исходном коде шаблона не увидишь, если только не взломать систему и не скопировать весь сайт [:~)